# Online linear regression with sklearn.linear_model leads sklearn import linear_model error

Tags: scikit-learn

This fairly simple example leads to the error below? What is the problem and how can I solve it.

```
from sklearn import linear_model
from random import randrange

def model(x):
    return 2 * x

clf = linear_model.SGDRegressor()
for i in range(20000):
    x = randrange(-1000, 1000)
    clf.partial_fit([(1, x)], [model(x)])
```

> ValueError: Floating-point under-/overflow occurred at epoch #1. Scaling input data with StandardScaler or MinMaxScaler might help.

Comment: which sklearn version are you using? which python version (your code runs well in my machine). The randomness element has something to do with it most probably...

Comment: Your code works perfectly on my PC. I have python 3.4 with scikit-learn 0.16.0

Comment: Thanks that was the problem I used 0.15

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the random generator threw a number that made the matrix singular. You could try the "try-break" command to avoid the for from stopping at each error, skipping the errors instead.

(To see the try command: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html)